Evaluating $\lim\limits_{\nu\to1^{-}}\operatorname{li}(\nu^{2})-\operatorname{li}(\nu)$
I was considering methods for solving $\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{x-1}{\ln(x)}dx$ and I decided upon one that uses $\operatorname{li}(\nu)=\int\limits_{0}^{\nu}\frac{dx}{\ln(x)}$
$$\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{x-1}{\ln(x)}dx=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{2x}{2\ln(x)}dx-\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\ln(x)}dx=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{d(x^{2})}{\ln(x^{2})}-\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\ln(x)}=\lim\limits_{\nu\to1^{-}}\operatorname{li}(\nu^{2})-\operatorname{li}(\nu)$$
$\lim\limits_{x\to1}\operatorname{li}(x)=-\infty$ making this is $\infty-\infty$ so I tried to apply L'Hôpital's rule.
$$\lim\limits_{\nu\to1^{-}}\operatorname{li}(\nu^{2})-\operatorname{li}(\nu)=\ln\left(\lim\limits_{\nu\to1^{-}}\frac{e^{\operatorname{li}(\nu^{2})}}{e^{\operatorname{li}(\nu)}}\right)=\ln\left(\lim\limits_{\nu\to1^{-}}\frac{e^{\operatorname{li}(\nu^{2})}\frac{\nu}{\ln(\nu)}}{e^{\operatorname{li}(\nu)}\frac{1}{\ln(\nu)}}\right)=\ln\left(\lim\limits_{\nu\to1^{-}}\frac{e^{\operatorname{li}(\nu^{2})}}{e^{\operatorname{li}(\nu)}}\right)+\ln\left(\lim\limits_{\nu\to1^{-}}\nu\right)=\ln\left(\lim\limits_{\nu\to1^{-}}\frac{e^{\operatorname{li}(\nu^{2})}}{e^{\operatorname{li}(\nu)}}\right)$$
That achieved nothing. What's the right method then? A series expansion? It can't be around $0$, since $\operatorname{li}''(0)$ does not exist, so around $2$? Surely there must be a more elegant way than that.
Just to be clear, this is primarily about the limit, rather than the integral. Through Frullani's theorem, it's clear to see that $\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n}-1}{\ln(x)}dx=\ln(n+1)$ meaning $\lim\limits_{\nu\to1^{-}}\operatorname{li}(\nu^{2})-\operatorname{li}(\nu)=\ln(2)$, but what I want to know is how to get there through nothing but the defintion of $\operatorname{li}(x)$ and some clever tactics.

One idea is to pass from the log integral to the exponential function via $\text{li}(\nu)=\text{Ei}(t)$ where $t=\ln \nu$. This renders the limit as $\text{Ei}(2t)-\text{Ei}(t)\to \ln 2$ as $t\to 0$, and thus suggests looking at the series expansion of $\text{Ei}(t)$ near $t=0$.

If you do what @Semiclassical suggested, you have $$\text{Ei}(2t)-\text{Ei}(t)= \log (2)+t+\frac{3}{4}t^2+O\left(t^3\right)$$

You want the quantity $$
\lim_{\nu \to 1^-} \int_{\nu}^{\nu^2} \frac{dx}{\ln(x)}.
$$
using real analytic methods. Let $1>\gamma > \nu$ be arbitrary. We write $\gamma = \nu^{\alpha}$ where $\alpha = \frac{\ln \gamma}{\ln \nu}$ is such that $\alpha<1$. We have $$
\int_{\gamma}^{\gamma^{2}} \frac{dx}{\ln(x)} \overset{y^{\alpha} = x}{=} \int_{\nu}^{\nu^2} \frac{\alpha y^{\alpha-1} dy}{\ln(y^{\alpha})} = \int_{\nu}^{\nu^2} y^{\alpha-1} \frac{dy}{\ln(y)} > \int_{\nu}^{\nu^2} \frac{dy}{\ln(y)},
$$
Since $\alpha -1 < 0$ and $y<1$. Let $g_2(\nu) = \int_{\nu}^{\nu^2} \frac{dx}{\ln(x)}$ for ease. Then, $g_2(x)$ is an increasing function on $(0,1)$. For $\nu$ close enough to $1$, we can ensure that $0 > \ln(x) > -2$ on $[\nu,\nu^2]$ so that $g_2$ is bounded in a left neighbourhood of $1$. This means that $\lim_{\nu \to 1^-} g_2(x)$ exists and is a finite number.

Now, let $g_{r}(\nu) = \int_{\nu}^{\nu^r} \frac{dx}{\ln(x)}$ for any $r\geq 1$. The exact same logic that you saw above, when repeated appropriately, yields that $\lim_{\nu \to 1^-} g_r(x)$ exists and is a finite number.
Let $f(r) = \lim_{\nu \to 1^-} g_r(\nu)$ for $r \geq 1$. Note that for any $r,s\geq 1$,
$$
g_{rs}(\nu) = \int_{\nu}^{\nu^{rs}} \frac{dx}{\ln(x)} = \int_{\nu}^{\nu^{r}} \frac{dx}{\ln(x)} + \int_{\nu^{r}}^{\nu^{rs}} \frac{dx}{\ln(x)} = g_{r}(\nu) + g_{s}(\nu^{r}).
$$
Thus, $$
f(rs) = \lim_{\nu \to 1^-} g_{rs}(\nu) = \lim_{\nu \to 1^-} g_{r}(\nu) +\lim_{\nu \to 1^-} g_{s}(\nu^{r}) = f(r)+f(s)
$$
for all $r,s \geq 1$. Let $h(x) = f(e^x)$ for $x \geq 0$. Then, $$
h(rs) = f(e^{rs}) = f(e^{r})+f(e^s) = h(r)+h(s)
$$
for all $r,s \geq 1$.
Note that $g_r> g_s$ for $r<s$ since $g_r$ is the integration of the negative function $\frac{1}{\ln(x)}$ over a subinterval of the corresponding integral for $g_s$. So it follows that $f$ and hence $h$ are monotonic functions on $(0,\infty)$. A typical repetition of the Cauchy functional argument along with this assumption yields that $h(x) = cx$ for some constant $c$ and therefore that $f(r) = c \ln(r)$ for some constant $c$.
How to find the constant $c$ though? Note that $\ln(x)$ is a monotone function, therefore
$$
\frac{\nu^r-\nu}{\ln(\nu^r)}\leq \int_{\nu}^{\nu^r} \frac{dx}{\ln(x)} \leq \frac{\nu^r-\nu}{\ln(\nu)}
$$
for all $\nu \in (0,1), r \geq 1$. So, taking the limit as $\nu \to 1^-$ on both sides, $$
\frac{r-1}{r} \leq f(r) \leq r-1
$$
for all $r \geq 1$. Using $f(r) = c \ln(r)$ we have that $$
\frac{r-1}{r \ln r} \leq c \leq \frac{r-1}{\ln(r)}
$$
for all $r \geq 1$. A simple limit as $r \to 1^+$ of the above quantity yields that $c = 1$, and therefore that $f(r) = \ln(r)$ for all $r \geq 1$.
In particular, $f(2) = \ln(2)$ is the desired quantity.

Sarvesh, it seems that $\alpha<1$. Am I wrong?

@Angelo ah yes, thanks. Then the signs get reversed and I will make the required changes
